# How to choose replacement capacitor/inductor in a simple RLC blackbox?

Tags: capacitor, inductor, capacitance, inductance

Assuming there's a circuit that we can't see but we can guess how it works based on what it's made for. We know (or just are pretty sure) it's an RLC circuit with no digital parts. From what I've learned in EE basics, the voltage depends heavily on L & C in such circuits, mainly the inductance and capacitance values. Given the little information, here's what I think:

When changing a capacitor or inductor (just 1) in a blackbox circuit:

- The capacitance/inductance value should be the same as the original. Using different values may change the power waveform, which can increase or decrease the maximum voltage and/or make the voltage go up and down, making the system somewhat unstable.
- The voltage/wattage rating should be equal or higher. If it's lower, the component may burn out. Having it higher means better tolerance.

Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: That's pretty idealized. Most components also include parasitics and those can be very important depending on the situation. For example, capacitor ESR can make all the difference in how a voltage regulator functions (too little or too much can make it malfunction.)

Comment: This is supposed to be considered with the assumption that there are only 3 types of components and taking a risk in changing the values. It may be based on personal experience with how one often replaces such components. It's mostly making educated guesses and taking chances in this case.

Comment: I wasn't sure if you were talking practically, or theoretically. So I mentioned a thought. I'll hold short, now.